# How to implement cross app navigation and navigating back to the Fiori launchpad home?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

In our company, we've set up the Fiori launchpad. In it, we have configured a tile that is linked to a custom developed SAPUI5 app, which is deployed as a BSP on the server. It took us a long while, yet using the router pattern within that application, we managed to make the navigation from the launchpad tile to the custom UI5 application work.

The thing we are struggling with, however, are these 2 other navigation paths:

- From the application back to the Fiori launchpad (back home)
- From the application to another application (tile to tile)

Ideally, this out of application navigation is in the UI5 way, including a transition, so not just a `window.replace` in JS. After a long search, the only hint I've found in support for this scenario is in this class:

https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ushell.services.CrossApplicationNavigation

However, I don't understand how to use it. The example isn't even correct and has syntax errors. I've found two forum posts elsewhere asking about how to use it, but they lack any meaningful answer.

Comment: How do you navigate from the Launchpad to your application? Are you using in-place navigation with `Semantic Objects`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `Semantic Objects` for in-place navigation configured in your Launchpad to navigate to UI5 Applications you can navigate from one Application to another using the `CrossApplicationNavigation` service you already mentioned. However, the documentation about it is slightly confusing. This is how it works for me:

```
// Step 1: Get Service for app to app navigation
var navigationService = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");

// Step 2: Navigate using your semantic object
navigationService.toExternal({ 
                               target : { semanticObject : "<YourObject>", action: "<YourAction>" },
                               params : { A : "B" } // optionally
                            })
```

If you want to go back to your launchpad after in-place navigation you simply need to call

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

This still triggers the correct transition.

Comment: Hi Tim, for me, the window.history.go(-1) works only when I enter in my Fiori app, and press the back Button. If I click in one list item or item of detail view, it does not work, backing to the selected item list... Do you know how to avoid this error?