# How to open a Fiori App outside of the Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a simple Fiori app that is running in the launchpad. Now I am trying to start this app as standalone Fiori app because I don't need user information. The users should be able to call the app without logging in.

I have found a description how to call the app as standalone configuring the URL in the right way:

[Running an Application Standalone](https://help.sap.com/docs/UI_ADD-ON_FOR_SAP_NETWEAVER_20/17ae0e97e0fc424a9c368f350c0ba6bd/537758e0deb0477386ea400c915073b3.html?version=latest)

I gave that a try and it does not work in my case. No matter how I configure the URL, it directs me always to the Fiori Launchpad login screen.

Do I have to configure something in my app project to enable standalone? Or do I need to build the entire app as standalone?

Comment: Where is your app deployed to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate from launchpad to Fiori apps and then back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611228/how-to-navigate-from-launchpad-to-fiori-apps-and-then-back)